# for loop in Return

Tags: function, c++11, return

I'm a beginner in C++ and i have a problem that i dont know how to solve it,

I have an int function that few parameters should be return on it:

```
int sphere(const float & X,const float & Y,const float & Z, 
           const int & Px, const int & Py, const int & Pz, 
           const int & diameterOfSphere, const int & number) 
{
     return pow(Px-X,2) + pow(Py+(diameterOfSphere * (number - 1))-Y,2)
             + pow(Pz-Z,2) <= pow(diameterOfSphere/2,2); 
}
```

in this function, the integer "number" may should be start from 2 to for example 100. I need to do something that if i choose 100 for "number", the return statement should be repeated 99 times and separated by a plus ( + ).

for example i can do it manually but it is needed to write a lot of codes which is not logical

for example, i did it manually for just three times

```
 return (pow(Px-X,2)+pow((Py+(diameterOfSphere * 2))-Y,2)+pow(Pz-Z,2) 
   <= pow(diameterOfSphere/2,2)) 

  + (pow(Px-X,2)+pow((Py+(diameterOfSphere * 3))-Y,2)+pow(Pz-Z,2) 
   <= pow(diameterOfSphere/2,2)) 

  + (pow(Px-X,2)+pow((Py+(diameterOfSphere * 4))-Y,2)+pow(Pz-Z,2) 
   <= pow(diameterOfSphere/2,2)) 

  + (pow(Px-X,2)+pow((Py+(diameterOfSphere * 5))-Y,2)+pow(Pz-Z,2) 
   <= pow(diameterOfSphere/2,2)) ;
```

Is there any easier way? I know i have to use a loop but i dont know how to do it in this case

Thanks a lot

Comment: Jesus dude, didn't they teach you how to break down the function into lines which represent each step? This is hardly readable or maintainable...

Comment: Your use of `<=` is confusing to me. Are you trying to return a boolean value in the first block of code? More importantly, the last line is too long, and is most likely incorrect.

Comment: sorry, i could not break it here.
i used this code to separate a sphere for a simulation, it worked well, and i can manually generated more sphere in a row. But since i need more than 100 sphere, it need a lot of work to do it manually. but the manual version of the code is working well

Comment: "return repeated many times" ... please read good book about C++. Hard to understand Your chaos

Comment: @Jacek Cz It's hard to master programming without mastering English speech :P

Comment: why reference parameters? Probably You use code without understanding

Comment: @Jacek Cz in general that could be good idea for recursion, but in this case  reference would likely  not saving any stack space.. unless compiler can do something clever with global variables. If we would have a  3d point structure , that would be different.

Comment: @Swift I can agree const & struct may have sense, I guess author copy & paste code from somewhere. Hard to understand goal, function has name 'sphere' so ... it returns whole sphere object??? Not. Name sphereVolume???  Maybe. Good name is important start of good code

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `pow()` to do <strike>spheres</strike> squares, pow() is an exponential function that is quite slow. Break your formula and format your lines to make code readable. **Your point's coordinates are integer, is that intentional?** This variant is not only more readable, it's more likely to be optimized by compiler:

```
int sphere(const float & X,const float & Y, const float & Z, 
           const int & Px, const int & Py, const int & Pz,
           const int & diameterOfSphere, const int & number) 
{
 const float dx = Px - X;
 const float dy = Py + diameterOfSphere * (number - 1) - Y;
 const float dz = Pz - Z;
 const float D = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;

 return D <= 0.25 * diameterOfSphere*diameterOfSphere;
}
```

Now if I understood you right, you need a recursion or a loop that emulates recursion. You actually can call function from itself, do you know that?

```
int sphere(const float & X,const float & Y, const float & Z, 
           const int & Px, const int & Py, const int & Pz,
           const int & diameterOfSphere, const int & number) 
{
 const float dx = Px - X;
 const float dy = Py + diameterOfSphere * (number - 1) - Y;
 const float dz = Pz - Z;
 const float D = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz;

 if(!(number>0)) 
        return 0;
 return D <= 0.25 * diameterOfSphere*diameterOfSphere 
            + sphere(X,Y,Z,Px,Py,Pz,diameterOfSphere, number -1);
}
```

Negative side of recursion a) each function call fills stack with variables and parameters stored b) there is an extra call that returns immediately.

`Py + diameterOfSphere * (number - 1) - Y` expression throws me back, is that a mistake? Pretty much it almost never would cause comparison to be true. And it's still not clear what you're trying to do with those comparisons. So, while I modified code so it would be equal to your idea, it looks chaotic\senseless. The >= or <= would return  1 or 0 as result. Or did you mean this?

```
return ( D <= 0.25 * diameterOfSphere*diameterOfSphere )
            + sphere(X,Y,Z,Px,Py,Pz,diameterOfSphere, number -1);
```